# In a range of cells with similar formulas, how to make some of the values change to a absolute and some remain variable?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Here's my problem:

I have a sheet of over 3MB in excel, and i need a formula to cover all of the lines of the sheet, the formula in the first line being, e.g.: `=A1/B1`.

But there is a catch, i need the column B to keep repeating between lines 1 and 400. Therefore line 401 would be `A401/B1`, line 402 `A402/B2`, and so on.

Manually my idea was to add `$` to the number in column `B` till cell 400 and copypaste all the cells in the consecutive lines, but i have to do this on every single cell till line 400 and it takes too much time (and in the real sheet there are 15 formulas i need to do this procedure).

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `INDIRECT` to be able to change the reference each time.

```
=A1/INDIRECT("B"&IF(MOD(ROW(),400)=0,400,MOD(ROW(),400)))
```

On row 1, `MOD(ROW(),400)` evaluates to `1`, so that we get `A1/B1`.

On row 400, `MOD(ROW(),400)` evaluates to `0`, so the `IF` puts the value as `400`, so that we get `A400/B400`, which is still good.

On row 401, `MOD(ROW(),400)` evaluates to `1`, so that we get `A401/B1`.

Now, be sure to start on row 1, even if you evaluation doesn't. You can always copy/paste the values when you're done and remove the values on the first row(s) if you need to put column headers or something there.

Comment: Nice answer.  I'd use the int() function instead of "if" and "mod" to make it even more compact though:  =A1/INDIRECT("B"&INT((ROW()-1)/400)+1)

Comment: Actually your solution can work even if i dont start on row 1, by adding or subtracting from the row() function.

I usually dont use arithmetics in formulas but you proofed it can be quite useful and ill start using it!

Comment: @user2425509 I made that formula on the go like that, and was thinking on another formula somewhere else, so yeah ^^; Nice to see that you can adapt it do your needs :)

Comment: @Gerrat Does that really work? For row 1, there's nothing wrong, for row 2, we get `INT((ROW()-1)/400)+1` evaluating to 1 again, where we'd expect 2.

Comment: Ah, I think I misread his question...thought he wanted the B1 repeated 400 times, then B2, etc.

Comment: @Gerrat Oh! Yes, if that was so then that would be working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

`INDIRECT` function is best avoided if you can because it's a "volatile" function - meaning that it always re-calculates whenever the worksheet is re-calculated, even if none of the dependant values change - that can increase calculation times.

If you use `INDEX` here you can avoid that overhead.....and you can also avoid "hard-coding" the column letter, i.e. this formula in C1 copied down

`=A1/INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROWS(C$1:C1)-1,400)+1)`

Note that use of `ROWS` function instead of `ROW` allows you to insert rows above without affecting the results - you can start from any cell just change the `ROWS` function to match the start cell